# Getting and/or ejecting all implementations of a generic interface using structuremap

Tags: c#, .net, generics, structuremap

I currently have an interface of

```
public interface IHandle<T> where T : ICommand
{
  void Invoke(T command);
}
```

In structure map I can get any specific implementation of a IHandle with the following type of calls, so I know that all of my handlers exist in StructureMap.

```
var commandHandler = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IHandle<SomeCommand>>();
```

However what I would like to do is either get (or eject as thats my eventual goal) all instances if IHandle.

I've tried the following with no success

```
// compile error because it doesn't have a type
ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<>>();

// returns 0 items
ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<ICommand>>();

// has runtime error of "Cannot create arrays of open type."
ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(typeof(IHandle<>));
```

Does anyone know how to get all instances of a generic interface?

Thanks for any help

Comment: The `T` could be [`in`, not `out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx), so `IHandle<ICommand>` wouldn't make sense without casting. How are you planning to use these `IHandle<>` instances?

Comment: I want to eject them all from StrctureMap. I have a Web app that uses the same plugins as a Queues app. So in the Web app - I want to remove all the Command handlers, so only Queues app will run them in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to eject them, then you can use the following code:

```
ObjectFactory.Model.EjectAndRemovePluginTypes(x => 
    x.IsGenericType &&
    x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IHandle<>)
    );
```

Getting all the instances is possible but you can only store them as `System.Object` or `dynamic`. You can't cast them to what you have tried `IHandle<ICommand>`. This isn't allowed because if it would type safety could no longer be maintained.

BTW this is not the reason why `ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<ICommand>>();` returns zero items. This is because there are simply no instances of plugin type`IHandle<ICommand>` registered. You probably don't have types that implement `IHandle<ICommand>` but you perfectly can create and register them and get them with `ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<ICommand>>()`.

So if `System.Object` or `dynamic` instances are ok you can do the following:

```
IEnumerable<IPluginTypeConfiguration> handlers =
    ObjectFactory.Model.PluginTypes
                       .Where(x => x.PluginType.IsGenericType &&
                                   x.PluginType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == 
                                                       typeof (IHandle<>));

var allInstances = new List<object>();

foreach (IPluginTypeConfiguration pluginTypeConfiguration in handlers)
{
    var instancesForPluginType = 
              ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(pluginTypeConfiguration.PluginType)
                           .OfType<object>();

    allInstances.AddRange(instancesForPluginType);
}
```

Change `object` to `dynamic` for the dynamic approach.